# Multi MXD export excluding specific MXD using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, export, pdf

I try to export multi MXD into pdf files, but i want to exclude specific MXD files from this action:

```
import arcpy,os
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"D:\desktop\Project"
for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\desktop\Project\\" + mxd)
    if 'project2' or 'project3' in mxd:
        pass
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mapdoc, r"D:\desktop\Project\out\\"+os.path.basename(mapdoc.filePath).replace ('.mxd','') +".pdf")
    print mxd
    mapdoc.save() 
del mxd
```

But the result is that all MXD files has been exported:

```
 >>> 
project.mxd
project2.mxd
project3.mxd
>>>
```

Comment: While both answers are technically correct, they differ in which mxd's that are exported: those which contains project2 or project3, or those that doesn't.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is a Python rather than ArcPy issue because it is really about constructing `if`/`else` and using `pass` statements.  I'm just saying this to try and help you see that when you write a Python script that imports ArcPy there will be some parts better researched at [so].

Comment: @Martin, good point. I've updated my answer to cover both cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `pass` which will do nothing, but jumps to the next code row.

Do it like this:

```
for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\desktop\Project\\" + mxd)
    if 'project2' not in mxd and 'project3' not in mxd:
      arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mapdoc, r"D:\desktop\Project\out\\"+os.path.basename(mapdoc.filePath).replace ('.mxd','') +".pdf")
      print mxd
      mapdoc.save() 
del mxd
```

This will export all mxds except those which contain the specified strings. If you need to export only project2 and 3, then just remove `not in` and use `or`, so it will be:

```
if 'project2' in mxd or 'project3' in mxd:
```

It is also important to understand the syntax of evaluation in Python. When you wrote

```
if 'project2' or 'project3' in mxd:
```

This will always evaluate to `True` because 'project2' is not an empty string (empty strings will evaluate to `False`). Look here for [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531832/3346915).

Instead, you should always complete the evaluation by providing the right part of the check: `if 'project2' in mxd and 'project3' in mxd`.

If you have many mxd names to check, you might end up having very long conditions. In this cases, you could use [`any`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work).

```
mxds_to_skip = ["project1","project2","project3","project4"]
print any(k in "project3" for k in mxds_to_skip)
>>> True
print any(k in "project7" for k in mxds_to_skip)
>>> False
```

Comment: The `pass` statement is one issue. The other main issue with the OP's code is that `if 'project2' ` will *always* evaluate to True. I know your code fixes this, but your answer would be improved if you explained why.

Answer (score 3):

I want to come at this from a different direction and show you how you can test the logic in each of the answers by using purely Python rather than ArcPy.  I may or may not have copied/understood each of their logics but I don't think that matters because what I am trying to show is how you can test them, and in particular experiment with yours.

```
mxdList = ["project.mxd","project2.mxd","project3.mxd"]

print "Your coding pattern"
for mxd in mxdList:
        if 'project2' or 'project3' in mxd:
            pass
        print mxd

print "AlexTereshenkov coding pattern 1"
for mxd in mxdList:
    if 'project2' not in mxd and 'project3' not in mxd:
      print mxd

print "AlexTereshenkov coding pattern 2"
for mxd in mxdList:
    if 'project2' in mxd or 'project3' in mxd:
      print mxd

print "Midavalo coding pattern"
for mxd in mxdList:
    if 'project2' or 'project3' in mxd:
        pass
    else:
      print mxd

print "Stefan coding pattern"
for mxd in mxdList:
    if 'project2' or 'project3' in mxd:
        print mxd


>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Your coding pattern
project.mxd
project2.mxd
project3.mxd
AlexTereshenkov coding pattern 1
project.mxd
AlexTereshenkov coding pattern 2
project2.mxd
project3.mxd
Midavalo coding pattern
Stefan coding pattern
project.mxd
project2.mxd
project3.mxd
>>>
```

Comment: Good answer, being along the lines of [teaching to fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)!

Comment: Thanks @Martin When I was new to Python and arcgisscripting/ArcPy I think it was when I began to understand where they started and pure Python ended that made a lot of things fall into place.  You may want to look in on http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4058/where-is-the-line-between-python-and-gis - if you have not already.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your export into an `else`

```
for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\desktop\Project\\" + mxd)
    if 'project2' in mxd or 'project3' in mxd:
        pass
    else:
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mapdoc, r"D:\desktop\Project\out\\"+os.path.basename(mapdoc.filePath).replace ('.mxd','') +".pdf") 
        print mxd 
        #mapdoc.save()
```

Your `if` doesn't excluded files as the `else` is missing.

EDIT: Updated to correct the `if` statement that I missed last night.  Also I don't think the mapdoc.save() is required here, unless you need to resave your mxd.